# boost python with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, boost, crash

It seems boost::python and boost::thread don't really like each other for what I can tell.

Please refer to http://pastebin.com/Cy123mJK

This is a simplification of the problems I am having with my boost::python and boost::thread-based application.

If anyone can tell me why these problems are occurring; I have no clue, since I strictly make sure python interaction is done with one thread at once.

At some point, the program crashes with a segfault for no obvious reason. Also, it's impossible to catch this crash it seems...

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running python in multiple threads at the same time in `Producer::run()` and `Consumer::run()`.

To be exact, you run this before locking the mutex:

```
boost::python::object writer = this->k->Get<boost::python::object>("write");
```

Maybe you didn't realize that Boost eventually calls `PyObject_GetItem` when you call `boost::python::object::operator[](const std::string&)` in `Keeper::Get`. You need to move that Get-call to the correct location, after locking and before using the returned function:

```
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(this->k->python_keeper);
  boost::python::object writer = this->k->Get<boost::python::object>("write");
  writer(boost::python::str(os.str()));
}
```

Edit: Removed `Py_Finalize()`. Yes you are right, boost.python doesn't like it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have incorporated your suggestion in the test program, it's running at the moment. Also, boost::python documentation claims `Py_Finalize()` shouldn't be called: http://ur1.ca/2zuwb

Comment: The test program has been running since my last comment without interruption. I thank you for spotting my thinking error!